# Missing microsoft component for SSIS task

Tags: c#, dll, ssis

The library Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask is missing from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\

Is there another location where this dll might be?

Requirement: To set the type of sql statement to variable in the package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.executesqltask.sqlstatementsourcetype.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the dll in the task folder.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Tasks\Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask.dll**